# envio de correo mediante Lambda, Nodejs y SES no funcionausando documentacion de AWS

Tags: nodejs, aws, lambda

Tengo una función en Lambda con NodeJs; estoy intentando enviar un correo electrónico mediante SES, Pero cuando llamo la función esta no realiza ninguna acción y tampoco genera registros de errores en CloudWatch. He consultado la documentación en la plataforma de AWS y de esta manera obtuve la siguiente función:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({
    accessKeyId: 'key',
    secretAccesskey: 'secret',
    region: 'eu-west-1'
});

module.exports.correo = function(event, context) {
    console.log("Incoming: ", event);
    var output = querystring.parse(event);

    var eParams = {
    Destination: {
     ToAddresses: ["test@email.mx"]
    },
    Message: {
     Body: {
      Text: {
       Data: output.Key1
      }
     },
     Subject: {
      Data: "Ses Test Email"
     }
    },
    Source: "test@email.mx"
};

console.log('===SENDING EMAIL===');
var email = ses.sendEmail(eParams, function(err, data){
    if(err) {
     console.log(err);
     context.fail(err);
    };
    else {
     console.log("===EMAIL SENT===");
     console.log("EMAIL CODE END");
     console.log('EMAIL: ', email);
     console.log(data);
     context.succeed(event);
    }
});};
```

Pero esto es lo que obtengo como resultado de registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero seria validar los permisos de tu función Lambda, muy posiblemente hace falta algún permiso para llamar a SES. Ademas, verificar si tu lambda tiene permisos para escribir logs en CloudWatch. (el rol asociado debería tener este permiso también)

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar mensajes mediante SES se debe primero [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]validar el dominio del correo que se use como sender o en su defecto validar el correo que se use como sender.

Además veo que en el code, en el if hay un punto y coma (;) que no debería ir